# How to read a csv or text file using c# and count characters line by line of that file and show if less than 1500?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to read a csv or text file using c# and count characters line by line of that file and show at the end of the line of which character count is less than 1500? I can count total number of characters, but i can't count characters of line by line...It may be a silly question to the C# experts, but i just started coding in c#, i would also love to know what is the best way to be a proficient c# coder???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your question to mean you want to know at which line is the total character count of the document less than 1500:

```
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
        int count = 0;
        int line = 0;

        for (; line < lines.Length; line++)
        {
            count += lines[line].Length;
            if (count >= 1500)
            {
                // previous line is < 1500
                Console.WriteLine("Character count < 1500 on line {0}", line - 1);
                Console.WriteLine("Line {0}: {1}", line - 1, lines[line - 1]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use LINQ:

```
var shortLines = File.ReadLines("file.csv")
                     .Where(line => line.Length < 1500);

foreach (var line in shortLines)
{
    // Do whatever you need to
}
```

Note that this will only read the file when you iterate over `shortLines`, and it will stream it - but it *does* mean that if you iterate over `shortLines` twice, it'll read it twice. If you need to iterate over those lines more than once, call `ToList` after `Where`.

Answer (score 0):

```
string completeFile = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\somefile.txt");

string[] arrayOfLines = completeFile.Split('\n');

foreach(string singleLine in arrayOfLines)
{
    //count
}
```

Comment: That may leave trailing `\r` characters, and requires the whole file to be read in one go. .NET can handle the line breaks for you, and also stream the file - see my answer.